# Use HDFS from mount point vs. Hadoop's FileSystem class

Tags: java, hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

In a java program, is it more efficient to read/write HDFS files through java.io.File from a mount point, or to use Hadoop's API with the FileSystem class? Are there other criteria to consider besides efficiency (io time).

Comment: Depends how you created that mount point to your local disk. It'd be using equivalently the same API to reach the NameNode + Datanodes

Comment: I used NFS for the mount.

Comment: Do you have something against using the FileSystem class?

Comment: Nothing except it's a little bit more code and I wanted to know if there is any performance gain (the NFS mount was already done for convenience)

Comment: The only thing I can think of other than IO rates would be related to user permissions in that the NFS user is only a single account that you couldn't monitor on the cluster who accesses files though it more granularly

Comment: Thanks, that is useful to know. I'll be running some tests to know more about the difference in IO, if there is, it can become significant for big data jobs.

Comment: It definitely won't be as fast as MapReduce or Spark